# Create Deezer player

Tags: deezer

I have a problem when trying to integrate the new Deezer SDK in my application.
I keep getting an UnsatisfiedLinkError when trying to create a player.
I manage to login to Deezer through the SDK and even to access the playlists/tracks, but I can't create the player.

I added libdeezer.so in both armeabi and armeabi-v7a folders. Does anybody have any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, it was my fault.
I have a script that is copying the libraries in my project; the libdeezer.so was being replaced by the old library.